# What is the way to ask about someone's partner?

Tags: questions, interrogatives

If my friend **has got married to someone** and I would like to ask my 3rd friend about him and his bride, what is the way to ask this?

I thought about two options:

> a) *"Whom have he got married to?"*
>
> b) *"Whom did he get married to?"*

Are they correct?

Comment: "To whom did he get married?", or more simply (and colloquially): "Who did he marry?"

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use "have got"? It is unnecessary. Also where you wrote "If my friend have got married to someone...", "If my friend got married to someone..." or "If my friend married someone..." is fine.

Comment: Agree with both the above that most native speakers would simply ask *Who did he marry?* Note that [***Whom** did you marry?*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Whom+did+you+marry%2CWho+did+you+marry&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhom%20did%20you%20marry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWho%20did%20you%20marry%3B%2Cc0) is hopelessly outdated to most of us today, even though many of us are perfectly well aware that since ***Him*** is a credible one-word answer (and ***He*** isn't), then *technically speaking* it should be ***whom***, not ***who***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Hopelessly" may overstate the case, don't you think? Surely we haven't come so far that the use of _whom_ is viewed with disapproval or alarm! If I were to be asked "whom did you marry?" I would think the locution charming, a little formal, but not entirely out of band. Also, it's a register thing. It might discomfit the plumber, but my doctor wouldn't bat an eye.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I certainly *don't* think "hopelessly" overstates the case there. My NGram link primarily reflects *written* instances, which tend to be quite some way behind real-world *spoken* language. Consider a context where your marriage is going through a rough patch, and you're musing aloud to yourself about whether your partner really *is* the person you thought they were when you got married. If you were a dyed-in-the-wool Victorian, you might ask yourself ***Whom** did I marry?* (but probably in that case she'd be "normal" anyway, and *you'd* be the out-of-touch pedantic weirdo! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use **whom** as the object of a verb in formal English.  When you do so, you generally use the *whom* after the necessary *preposition*. So the sentence should be:

> **To** whom did he get married?

However, it's very common to use *who* instead of *whom* as the object of a verb, especially in informal English. In this case, we use the preposition at the end of a sentence as follows:

> Who did he get married **to**?

You can also say Who did he marry? But the use of the phrase "get married" is more common.

As for the first sentence "Whom have he got married to?, it's ungrammatical; you don't use have for the third person. You use has for he.
So the right sentence is:

> **To** whom has he got married?